# Some good fully-featured OpenType typeface for body text

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, typefaces, typesetting, opentype

What are some good serif typefaces for body text which have at least Roman and Italic, and support small caps, old-style figures, ligatures, and super/subscripts? (And which, it goes without saying, have good—*hand-tuned*—kerning.)

Some obvious choices are the fonts which come with Adobe InDesign (Minion, Garamond, Caslon &c), but I'd like to know some other options.

And are there any open source (or at least freeware) fonts that fit this description?

Comment: Kerning by hand is a lot of work. I mean i can spit out a font in 20 hours (rush job, but more likely a manweek or 2 of work per subset), if it wasn't for kerning (hand kerning is well 10 times that amount of work). Therefore to find a font that has all that needs to have a sponsor, since it represents at minimum 6 months of commitment on the maker. So you wouldn't find many such fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a highly subjective question, since what one person considers good, another might consider bad.  However, you might want to take a look at [Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=87&L=1) which has small caps, ligatures, and OpenType features.

I have no affiliation with the Linux Libertine website

Answer (score 0):

STIX Two Text is good for small print. Although it was designed for maths typesetting, of course it works perfectly in general-purpose use. It has quite a high x-height so perhaps best suited for smaller-print text. The makers describe it as based on 10pt text.